# pci_map_sg failing in (PCIe) DMA driver when the buffer is allocated using malloc

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I have a custom PCIe card with DMA engine.
I am trying to allocate userspace memory for DMA using **malloc** (non-page-aligned), then **get_user_pages_fast**(tried normal get_user_pages also) and then calling **pci_map_sg** on that pages on a Qualcomm arm64 platform.
In this specific device, after allocating a total of ~256 MB (after reboot) of memory using malloc (with numerous iterations) the pci_map_sg fails.

After getting the error, all subsequent pci_map_sg fails, until reboot.

It seems that some buffer of 256 MB is getting depleted while using malloc/get_user_pages_fast/pci_map_sg but I didn't get any info from meminfo. Everything looks normal in meminfo and free.

All the memory allocations/deallocations pinning/unpinning are in order and correct. Didn't find any possible leak.

Also, this issue is occurring only in non-page aligned buf. If using valloc instead of malloc, the issue is not occurring.
Page aligned buffer allocated using mmap also passes with no error.

Any kind of pointers or help is really appreciated.

Note that this driver works in other platforms (x86_64, arm64(NVidia Jetson, iMX8))

Comment: Side note: `pci_map_sg()` is deprecated, you shouldn’t use it in a new code.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, forgot to mention this in the question. I did try with ```dma_map_sg``` too. But still getting the same error.

Comment: "Didn't find any possible leak" doesn't mean there is no leak. It's hard to tell without seeing the code.

Comment: The same driver works in other platforms without any issue, and the regression is run for weeks, meaning millions of iterations.
On this platform(Qualcomm), only the first 15 iterations run successfully, and the 16th fails. If there were any leaks, it would get hit in any of the other platform. Also, I had verified this code section to find possible leaks multiple times without finding anything. That's why I said there were no possible leaks.
This is more of a theoretical question, rather than code debugging.

Comment: I am sure the code is fine, it follows the above flow, but is there anything on Linux memory management that I need to check, or is there any limitation for malloc, which might cause this?

Comment: Some things to check: (1) The address passed to `get_user_pages_fast()` is page-aligned; (2) `put_page()` is being called on all the pages in the page array filled by `get_user_pages_fast()` (after marking modified pages as dirty); (3) If a temporary buffer was allocated for the list of pages, the buffer is being freed; (4) If a temporary buffer was allocated for the SG list, the buffer is being freed.

Comment: All of the above were done except part of (2). The pages aren't marked as dirty before calling ```put_page()```. Will try that and update.

Comment: Marking the pages dirty also didn't have any effect. Still showing the same behavior.